# How to enlarge object area on mask

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am working on a computer vision project and I need to extract the object from the image with preprocessing so I can eliminate noise and redundant parts in the image.

What I am trying to do is multiplying image by a mask that is thresholded image so except field of the object, other pixels will equalize to 0.

To do that I determine a threshold value. And I get below mask
[image]

After that I decrease the resolution and increase it.

[image]

[image]

At the end I want to smooth the edges of the last mask so I can be sure to get the whole object. Is there a method for this?

Green surrounded area in the below image represent the shape of field I ask.
(Background image is a combination of first and third images.)

[image]

Comment: No point to reduce and expand the image. Just use morphology open and then close or dilate to first remove extraneous regions to smooth it (i.e. open) and then use close or dilate to fill it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into the dilation operation:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html

You'll need to fine tune the iterations and the size of the dilation to get a closer result to what you want.